# Sqlite database encryption in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption

In my iOS app I encrypted database using SQLCipher. But after encrypting database the performance of the app is degrade. So I want to ask that, is there any other way to encrypt database. Can I use file encryption for this using NSFileProtectionComplete.

OR

There is any other way to encrypt database which does't compromise with the performance of app.

Thank you.

Comment: I've never noticed significant degradation of performance using SqlCipher.

Comment: @HotLicks But I am still facing this problem. Now I am using CommonCrypto. But it is very helpful for me if you send me code, how you implement SqlCipher.

Comment: CommonCrypto, from what I can tell, is an encryption kit, not a database.